Create preview for running virtually hosted html files
I recently as a project coded a basic code editor using html/JavaScript that lets you edit files in a git repository after you input a GitHub personal access token. there's a file explorer and an input to edit the file and a commit button. I wanted to add a preview option to see a basic preview for changes not yet committed and I was wondering if it was possible and how?
I was thinking maybe temporarily host it on local storage or a js worker - but I don't know how relative links would work then - e.g.: <script src="../script.js"\>
many thanks!
I uploaded it so far onto this repl

(the files were too big to put snippets here)

